# Passing part of a viewmodel to a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, model, controller

I have a Customer index page that takes a CustomerIndexViewModel to populate the page with a list of customers, the time the request took, and many other pieces of information.

I have a CustomerSearchArgsModel inside the CustomerIndexViewModel.

```
public class CustomerIndexViewModel : BaseIndexViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers{ get; set; }
    public double RequestTime { get; set; }
    public CustomerSearchArgsModel CustomerSearchArgsModel { get; set; }
    public OtherTypes OtherType {get;set;}
}


public class CustomerSearchArgsModel
{
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

On my Customer Index page I want to have something like -

```
@model CustomerIndexViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Customer",FormMethod.Post, new { id="searchSubmit"}))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerSearchArgsModel.ConsumerID)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerSearchArgsModel.ConsumerID)
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerSearchArgsModel.LastName)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerSearchArgsModel.LastName)
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerSearchArgsModel.FirstName)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerSearchArgsModel.FirstName)

    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

I want to return the typed in values to the Index (POST) method on the Customer controller in a CustomerSearchArgsModel.

But I don't know how to return a Model that is different from the one defined at the top of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your "searchSubmit" form inside a partial view. Then pass the **model.CustomerSearchArgsModel** to the partial view. Be sure that  **model.CustomerSearchArgsModel** is not null; otherwise, you will get an exception.

**Index Page**

```
@Html.Partial("_search", model.CustomerSearchArgsModel)
```

**_search Partial View**

```
@model CustomerSearchArgsModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Customer",FormMethod.Post, new { id="searchSubmit"}))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConsumerID)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConsumerID)
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)

    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

The problem with this approach is you will get a 0 value displayed in your textbox for ConsumerID. To solve this problem you can use Html.Action instead of Html.Partial.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that sorted it.